# Prove there is a sequence of points in a bounded nonempty subset S of R with the limit = sup S

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

$S$ is a bounded nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sup S$ is not in $S$.  Prove there is a sequence $s_n$ in $S$ such that $\lim s_n = \sup S$.

**Proof:**

Any sequence $s_n$ where $\sup s - s_n < 1/2^n$ for all $n$ clearly converges to $\sup S$.

Such a sequence exists with all $s_n$ in $S$, as follows:  Given any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $s$ in $S$ such that $\sup S - s < \epsilon$.  If not, $\sup S - \epsilon$ would be an upper bound on $S$.

Comment: I think you should be clearer about how you used the definition of *supremum*, i.e. *least upper bound*. The definition of supremum according to Rudin has two key properties and you should use these properties in your proof. As it stands, I think all you've done is use your intuitive notion of supremum, which isn't good enough if you want to be rigorous. So it depends on how rigorous you want to be.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I desire to be rigorous. A clarifying sentence added.

Comment: This may help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004108/how-can-i-show-a-supremum-of-a-set-is-also-its-limit-point

Comment: Your proof is correct, but rather lazy. If all you care about is the essence of your proof, then it's probably fine. But you leave out lot of stuff and make the reader to quite a bit of work to fill in the "gaps" in your proof, e.g. when you saying "clearly" in your second line - a classic "proof by lol obvious". And linking your first line with your second and 3rd lines. Stop making me, the reader, fill in the gaps for you in my head. Lay everything out there - starting with the definitions - like Xander Henderson did in his answer in the link above.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I don't believe that the line "Any sequence..." would be clarified by citing the epsilon definition of a sequence converging and showing for any epsilon > 0 the Archimidean property shows there exists an n s.t. 1/2^n < eps.  Writing that out would distract the reader, not make it more rigorous.