# Proving Sup(A+B) = Sup(A)+Sup(B), I got a question on something

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

$A,B $ : Nonemtpty bounded sets on R

I'm proving on $\sup(A+B) \geq \sup (A)+\sup(B)$

prove by contradicting assumption: $\sup(A+B) < \sup(A) + \sup(B)$

Then $\sup(A+B) -\sup (B)< \sup (A)$

Then there exists $a \in  A$ such that  $\sup(A+B)-\sup(B)<a$

$\sup(A+B) -a <\sup(B)$...

(next steps are omitted)

Now, I have a question on this prove on existence of $a$

For exmaple, Let $\sup(A+B)=X, \sup(B)=Y$. Then $X-Y<\sup(A)$

For sure, $a\le\sup(A)$. Then, how can we know $X-Y<a?$

Or am I wrong on proving this?

Comment: How do you define $A+B$ for sets $A,B$?

Comment: @Koro by $a\in A, b\in B, a+b \in A+B$

Comment: @Koro So, by the definition, my question is trivial?

Comment: I don't think so. It's a very valid question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004108/how-can-i-show-a-supremum-of-a-set-is-also-its-limit-point

Comment: Your title is inconsistent with your post.

Comment: @LeeMosher why is that and what would be more better title?

Comment: "Inconsistent" is a bit strong, but it's just that your title is about an equation and your post is about only one of the inequalities.

Comment: @LeeMosher I understood your point, but when I posted this, I thought the "context" might be important. It may help readers to understand what I didn't understand. So I posted the title like it.

Comment: Fair enough....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah this is a good question to ask. The fact is that there *is* such an $a$ because the supremums $X$ and $Y$ are fixed, whereas $\sup(A)$ is a limit point (i.e. elements of $A$ get arbitrarily close to $\sup(A)$).

Let $\sup(A+B)=X, \sup(B)=Y$. Then $X-Y <\sup(A)$ is your assumption that you want to contradict.

Note that $\sup(A+B)$ and $\sup(B)$ are fixed. That is, $X-Y \in \mathbb{R}$ is fixed.  If $X-Y < \sup(A)$, (strict inequality), then there is a gap $r$ between them:
$$\sup(A) - (X-Y) = r > 0.$$

Recall that by definition, the supremum is a limit point of $A$: there exists a sequence $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^\infty \in A$ such that $a_i \rightarrow \sup (A)$. So there is an element of this sequence that is arbitrarily close to $\sup(A)$, i.e. some $a_k$ such that
$$\sup(A) - a_k < r.$$

Combine these two facts to see that $$ X-Y <a_k.$$

Comment: Why sup(A) is a limit point?

Comment: Being a limit point means that there are points in $A$ that are arbitrarily close to $\sup(A)$ (if the sup isn't already in $A$). If this *weren't* true, then you could see that the sup would have to be moved lower since there'd be a gap

Comment: Oh then, If max(A)= sup(A), then my question was trivial, and if max(A) != sup(A) then sup(A) is a limit point, so by your answer, it is correct, right?

Comment: Yes correct! (technically an **adherent** point, see this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3027126/884634 but for our purposes it is the same idea)

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer!

Comment: Sure! Good luck with your math

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple using the definition of supremum. The *actual* definition, which says nothing about subsequences and limit points.

By definition $\sup(S)$ is the least upper bound of $S$. Which means two things: (i) $\sup(S)$ is an upper bound for $S$ and (ii) if $\alpha<\sup(S)$ then $\alpha$ is *not* an upper bound for $S$.

What you want ask about is this:

> > If $\alpha<\sup(S)$ there exists $a\in S$ with $\alpha<a$.

Proof: Since $\alpha<\sup(S)$, $\alpha$ is not an upper bound for $S$, which in turn means precisely that there exists $a\in S$ with $a>\alpha$.